# Hide functionality in excel services

Tags: excel, sharepoint, ssas, pivot-table

We're using Excel Services to make pivottables and pivotcharts available to the user. Datasource is an SSAS cube. This way the end user can alter many things in a sheet, but we want the user to focus on certain aspects. E.g. in a sheet we want show a top 20 ranking and want to give the user the option to switch to a top 50 or 100 ranking - but not customize the filters in any other way. Is this at all possible with Excel services or should we look out for a different SharePoint reporting component?